# Latex editor for Red Hat

Tags: latex

Can anyone suggest me a good latex editor (GUI) for RedHat LInux. I have tex installed on my machine which is fine for compiling documents in command line mode, but without a GUI editor (with code completion facility) it is really difficult to draft a new tex document.

I have looked at Kile and I am not able to install it on my Redhat machine despite repeated attempts. Also two of the most popular GUI latex editors - Texnic center and Led don't have Linux versions :-(

Comment: You might want to ask this on [tex.stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/whats-a-good-multiplatform-text-editor-system), but first look the almost identical [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) already on the site.

Comment: I won't migrate this to tex.se because this is a "shopping and recommendation" type question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/)? From what I see [here](http://joysofprogramming.com/install-texmaker-fedora-rhel/) it should be available into the RH repositories.

Comment: Yeah, I could install texmaker on my RH machine. It seems fine for my purpose, as of now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about emacs with YaTeX mode though it's not a GUI for LaTeX? YaTeX provides a completion functionality for TeX commands. Emacs also has the dynamic abbreviation functionality (bound to Meta-/ key sequence by default) for any word in your text file. You can also customize emacs to invoke shell commands. Unless you definitely want to click a button to compile a LaTeX document, I think this may be a good option.

YaTeX Web site
http://www.yatex.org/

Comment: Sorry... not a big fan of the church of emacs. I am more comfortable with the editor of the beast ...Vi Vi Vi